# Can't install MongoDB on Ubuntu 20

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to install MongoDB using `sudo apt install mongodb-org` command. I got this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no version 20, there is a 20.04 and a 20.10 what are you using?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Also, please don't post the screenshots of terminal. You ca directly copy and paste Terminal text in the question. Screenshots make questions slower to load on slow connections and impossible to copy the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 20.04 then it is for you. Open the terminal and Run the following commands:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

Issue the following command to reload the local package database:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the latest stable version, issue the following:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

It will be succesfully installed.
To run it run the following commands :

```
sudo service mongod start
```

To check the status if `MongoDB` is Online or not run this command :

```
sudo service mongod status
```

To Stop `MongoDB`:

```
Sudo service mongod stop
```

To use `MongoDB` :

```
Mongo
```